# Further enhancing javascript code to retrieve video srcs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am testing some javascript codes in the chrome console to retrieve videos src from an instagram post, that contains more than 2 videos.

I can retrieve the 2 srcs just fine using the code bellow, as it seems what's loaded in DOM. However it doesn't get the rest of the videos in that single post.

https://www.instagram.com/p/Cz45oeXJhj8/

```
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('video')) {
  const src = el.getAttribute('src');
  if (src) {
    console.log(src);
  }
}
```

So I tried to implement some clicking logic to click the `next` button and retrieve more src links. It seems to be all over place, I can't dial it in just to get the same amount of srcs based on the amount of the posts. I am not sure if this is even the correct way of doing it.

Here is the code that crawls the posts:

```
function extractVideoSources() {
  for (const video of document.querySelectorAll('video')) {
    const src = video.getAttribute('src');
    if (src) {
      console.log(src);
    }
  }
}

function clickNextButtonAndExtract() {
  const nextButton = document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Next"]');
  if (nextButton) {
    nextButton.click();

    setTimeout(() => {
      extractVideoSources();
      clickNextButtonAndExtract(); 
    }, 2000); 
  }
}
clickNextButtonAndExtract();
```

Any ideas how could I logically implement it? Also so it's reliable. Does it also need to target the specific container?

Comment: "it's just for educational purposes" :D

Comment: your answer helped me solve it lol @ElvisAdomnica

Comment: Some extra motivation right there, ha ha. The way I would have approach this "for educational purposes" would be to learn how to use Instagram API and get all of a user media: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#reading

Comment: I looked in the API, I am not sure how limited it is, or what it can access and what not. Or even worse, does it require OAuth for it to even work? @ElvisAdomnica

Comment: everything you asked it written in the API documentation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seeks for information that's documented at the Instagram API

Comment: the API doesn't solve my issue, it requires authentication which is not feasible. @LajosArpad